# Cannot implicity convert a...list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have the following classes...

```
public class Order
{
    private Guid id;
    public Guid ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private List<Items> orderItems;
    public List<Items> OrderItems
    {
        get { return orderItems; }
        set { orderItems= value; }
    }

}

public class Item
{

    private Guid id;
    public Guid ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string itemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return itemName; }
        set { itemName = value; }
    }

}
```

Then within my application I try the following....

```
ACME.Order newOrder = new ACME.Order();
newOrder.ID = xxx
newOrder.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem> {
     new ACME.OrderItem {
         ID = xxx
         ItemName = xxx
     }
}
```

However I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<ACME.Item>'` to `ACME.Item[]`.  The strange thing as well is that all I don't have an "Add" option on any of my list objects.

Comment: You have a `public List<Items> OrderItems` property and tries to load it with a `new List<OrderItem>`. Just a typo?

Comment: Your classes and variables names are all messed up -> you have a class Item, but a List<Items>, then in your application you are creating a List<OrderItem> which isn't mentioned elsewhere as a class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application on the client side of a Web service?

If so, the proxy generator for .asmx and WCF Web services generates an array `T[]` on the client side where a service interface uses a `List<T>` (or, indeed, any other enumerated type).

Your application will need to cast the list to an array (use `.ToArray()`) to set the array property client-side.

Comment: Good spot - also note that there are options to use `List<T>` etc; `/collectionType` for svcutl.exe, etc

Comment: Thanks that worked just added the collection type line from svcutil and all works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **assuming** that `List<Items>` is a typo, and you mean `List<Item>` ? And is `OrderItem : Item`? Or is this another typo?

I'm making the assumption that `OrderItem : Item`...

With `public List<Item> OrderItems {...}`, it will have to be a `List<Item>`:

```
newOrder.OrderItems = new List<Item> {
     new ACME.OrderItem {
         id = xxx
     }
}
```

since lists aren't covariant, even in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring typos I would recommend turning your generic list on Order to auto initialize. Then you just always deal with the list directly instead of worrying about initialization when adding items. So something like:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        private List<Item> orderItems;
        public List<Item> OrderItems
        {
            get 
            {
                if (orderItems == null)
                    orderItems = new List<Item>();
                return orderItems; 
            }
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your application you would do something like:

```
        Order newOrder = new Order { ID = new Guid() };
        newOrder.OrderItems.Add( new Item() { ID = new Guid(), ItemName = "New Item"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newOrder.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem> {
     new ACME.OrderItem {
         ID = xxx
         ItemName = xxx
     }
```

Ignoring your typos, your new List should be created like

```
newOrder.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>() { new OrderItem { IX=1,Itemname="somename}}
```

I saw that you were missing the "()" after `new List<OrderItem>`

HTH